# after dynamically adding controls to a gridview, can no longer access controls or gv.selectedvalue

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I'm adding some fields to a gridview dynamically in the gv.DataBinding event.  I'm handling the selecting, paging and sorting in C#.  Everything renders properly on screen and I can see the data is loaded into the gridview.

```xml
<asp:GridView ID="gvPulledBills" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    OnDataBinding="gvPulledBills_DataBinding" OnRowDataBound="gvPulledBills_RowDataBound" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvPulledBills_SelectedIndexChanged"  
    AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="gvPulledBills_Sorting" 
    AllowPaging="true" PageSize="30" OnPageIndexChanging="gvPulledBills_PageIndexChanging"
    DataKeyNames="Id" SkinID="gridviewGray">
```

In the gv.SelectedIndexChanged event, I need to retrieve the Id of the row selected.  Id is stored in a HiddenField and the gv.DataKeyNames value is set to ID so I have two ways to retrieve it.

gv.SelectedValue works fine after the initial render.  However, when selecting a row after paging/sorting, the gv.SelectedValue returns null.  It behaves as if nothing was selected at all, even though my selected row markup is working correctly. Any suggestions on what I need to do to ensure the datakey is retrievable when binding columns dynamically?

Alternatively, I've tried accessing the hidden field directly rather than depending on the gv.SelectedValue...

```cs
protected void gvPulledBills_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
    //var key = (int)gv.SelectedValue;
    var index = gv.SelectedIndex - (gv.PageIndex * gv.PageSize);
    var row = gv.Rows[index];
    var hiddenField = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("hdnId");
    var key = int.Parse(hiddenField.Value);
    ...
}
```

but the controls collections are empty in every cell, even for explicitly declared fields, even though there is data on the screen.
**Explicit declaration**

```xml
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

**Dynamic declaration**

```cs
private TemplateField CreateTemplateField()
{
    var controls = new List<Control>
    {
        { CreateHiddenIdField() }
    };
    var tf = GridViewTools.CreateTemplateField(string.Empty, string.Empty, controls);
    tf.ItemStyle.CssClass = "noRightBorder";
    tf.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "noBorder";
    return tf;
}
private static Control CreateHiddenIdField()
{
    var hdn = new HiddenField();
    hdn.ID = "hdnId";
    hdn.Value = "'<%# Eval(\"Id\") %>'";
    return hdn;
}
//in static class GridViewTools
public static TemplateField CreateTemplateField(string headerText, string sortExpression, List<Control> controls)
    {
        TemplateField tf = new TemplateField();
        tf.HeaderText = headerText;
        tf.SortExpression = sortExpression;
        tf.ItemTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(DataControlRowType.DataRow, controls);

        return tf;
    }

//... snippet that adds column to grid
    var addColumns = new List<DataControlField>();        
    addColumns.Add(CreateTemplateField());
    // add other columns
    foreach (var column in addColumns)
    {
        gv.Columns.Add(column);
    }
//...
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get the SelectedValue populated when using code behind paging/sorting with dynamic columns?  Or any suggestions on how to ensure the dynamically created field controls are populated and accessible in code behind?

I have many more columns added, mostly bound fields.  I'm doing this to customize the column set based on drop-down fields elsewhere on the page.  It's around 30 columns total and I would prefer not to add them all to the gridview, rather than just setting visibility on them all.

**UPDATE SOLUTION**
The final solution for this was:

```cs
var gv = (GridView)sender;
var rowIndex = gv.SelectedIndex - (gv.PageIndex * gv.PageSize);
var key = (int)gv.DataKeys[rowIndex]["Id"];
DisplayWorkDetail(key);
```

`SelectedRow` and `SelectedValue` are null at this point.  Only `SelectedIndex` is populated.  By converting the `SelectedIndex` to a RowIndex, I was able to retrieve the DataKey directly from the row.

I chose to use sender to make the code generic so I can easily extract it to a method for use with other GridViews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use sender here.

but, while the Rowcommand has NOT changed the selected index, in that index changed event, it HAS changed. So, you can directly use/reference the control

eg:

```
       GridViewRow myGv As GridViewRow = gvPulledBills.SelectedRow
```

and then:
myGv.RowIndex   (get/use row index).

But, you already have the row, so:

```
   hiddenField myField = (HiddenField)myGv.FindControl("hdnId");
   
   int MyKey = int.Parse(myField.Value);
```

You can also I suppose use the Datakeys collection and not even have that hidden field.

So, you could do this:

```
  GridViewRow myGv As GridViewRow = gvPulledBills.SelectedRow

  int RowPK = (int)(gvPulledBills.DataKeys[myGv.RowIndex]["ID"]);
```

Comment: SelectedRow is null just like SelectedValue.  The only Selected value populated is SelectedIndex.  I'm not using RowCommand at all.  Your answer did get me to a solution with  int RowPK = (int)(gvPulledBills.DataKeys[myGv.RowIndex]["ID"]);  so I'll mark it correct.